# on('click') not being called

Tags: onclick, jquery

I have a this code:

```
$('input.error').on('click', function(){
    $(this).removeClass('error').val($(this).data('submitval'));
});
```

But when I click on a form element with error class like so:

```
<input id="email" type="email" class="required error" placeholder="Enter Your Email here" name="email" value="">
```

Nothing happens, and the breakpoint I have set does not get called and none of the code executes. However if I set it to `$('input')` it does work. My understanding is that `.on` should cover for changes in the DOM after load. Am I missing something?

Comment: Why is that your understanding? Consider reading the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: dumb of me. the problem was that the first code sample on the API page is how *not* to do it :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are: `.on()` combines live events, delegates and regular events and the syntax you used creates a regular event.

What you wanted is

```
$('#someparentelement').on('click', 'input.error',function() {
    // ...
});
```

`#someparentelement` should be an element that is as close as possible to the input elements but exists at the time when you bind the event.